# Unable to save images taken using app?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, camera, storage

I have spent much time trying to resolve this trivial problem but seem to be going in circles even after reading many tutorials and previously asked questions.
I am a novice at programming but want to get better and believe that learning through mistakes is the best way.

Can someone please help identify the problem with this code and what can be done in order to allow the pictures taken by the device's camera to be saved onto the phone afterwards rather than being discarded and previewed.

Thanks in advance!

Java code for relevant class:

```
import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Activity_Camera extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static final int cameraData = 1;

    ImageButton ib;
    ImageView iv;
    Intent i;
    Bitmap bmp;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.Info:

            Intent i = new Intent(this, Help.class);
            startActivity(i);

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
        initialise();
    }

    private void initialise() {
        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPicReturn);
        ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibTakePic);

        ib.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.ibTakePic:
            i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            //
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getOutputMediaFileUri());
            //
            startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);
            break;
        }
    }
    //
    private String getOutputMediaFileUri() {
        File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImages");
        imagesFolder.mkdirs();   
        File image = new File(imagesFolder, "image.jpg");
        Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
        Intent imageIntent = null;
        imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);       
        return null;
    }
    //
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please edit in the relevant code (not the entire class) to your post.

Comment: What does `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you're returning null    `return null;` in your `getOutputMediaFileUri`

try this instead

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.ibTakePic:
        i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getOutputMediaFileUri());
        startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);
        break;
    }
}

private Uri getOutputMediaFileUri() {
    File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImages");
    imagesFolder.mkdirs();   
    File image = new File(imagesFolder, "image.jpg");
    return Uri.fromFile(image);
}
```

Comment: I have implemented the code and can now save an image!
The problem is the app now crashes afterwards and can only save a single image :/

What i can see from the getOutputMediaFileUri method is:
- A folder called MyImages is being created in the device's root
- image file is being saved as image.jpg in the directory
- being called through return function

Am i right in assuming the app is crashing because it doesn't know what to do after saving the file?
How might i go about rectifying this problem, anything after the return statement is "unreachable code".
Sorry for the basic q